# Empty newsletter tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, newsletter, bountied-tab

I love SE. I began with some newsletters, and then I created my account with the same email that I subscribed on newsletters. But I can see an empty newsletter tab. Is it normal? Do I resubscribe to newsletters with the account I have logged in with? Will I receive double news?

**More information**

I subscribed to the IT Security newsletter before to create my SE account. I try resubscribe to the IT Security newsletter when I logged. The system calls me to reconfirm by email and print on the page 'resend confirm'!

After I confirmed resubscribe, the newsletter tab was filled about all my subscriptions!

It is a small bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design:

First, you subscribed to 10 newsletters, including IT Security, *anonymously* (i.e. these subscriptions were not associated with a stackexchange.com user).

Then, you created a stackexchange.com user. The newsletters were not associated with your user at this time, since your email hadn't been confirmed yet.

When you then subscribed to IT Security while logged in, and subsequently confirmed your email address, the 10 anonymous subscriptions were automatically added to your account.